# how to configure cors so that swagger.json can be consumed from another origin to build .net blazor doc portal website

Tags: c#, cors, swagger, blazor, .net-7.0

I have a .net core 7 api (WebApplication1) and a blazor app (BlazorApp1). The api and blazor app have swagger installed and i want to consume the swagger/swagger.json in the blazor app to display the swagger ui in an iframe. However i cant figure out how to configure the api so that i dont get a cors error.

here is my WebApplication1/Program.cs

```
WebApplication1/Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var  myAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: myAllowSpecificOrigins,
        policy  =>
        {
            policy
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(myAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

here is my BlazorApp1/Program.cs

```
//BlazorApp1/Program.cs
using BlazorApp1.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options => options.SwaggerEndpoint("https://localhost:44323/swagger/v1/swagger.json","v1"));

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

WebApplication1 is running on https://localhost:44323
BlazorApp1 is running on https://localhost:7145

This is what i get no matter how i tweak the cors configuration in the api:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is what solved it:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
app.Use((ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "https://localhost:7145";
    return next();
});
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```